# PowerShell : How to count CRLF, but exclude LF

Tags: powershell

I'd like to count CR/LF but not LF in PowerShell.
Now I check the row count if the exported file corrected from database or not by following simple script.
But some data includes 'LF' and it failed to get correct row count.

```
Param(
    [string]$strFileName
)

Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
Write-Host "GET_FILE_ROWS_CNT.ps1"
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

$lines = 0
$fileReader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $strFileName
while ($fileReader.ReadLine() -ne $null)
{
    $lines++
}
$fileReader.close()
echo $lines
```

I'd like to count only CRLF, not LF. Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? The file has either CRLF or LF only, or a mix of CRLF and LF?

Comment: [``(Get-Content -Delimiter '`r`n'``).Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)

Comment: @zett42, I am doing this from my phone but intended to update my answer in the duplicate when I am home.

Comment: @iRon Thanks a lot for your kind advice :)

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks for your prompt action. It's mix of CRLF and LF in same line.

Comment: @iRon Variant using less memory and fix the quotation marks: `(Get-Content file.txt -Delimiter "\`r\`n" | Measure-Object).Count`

Comment: @zett42  Thanks a lot for your useful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the regex `\r\n` to count, and there's one `matches` property for each select-string match.  Get-content needs `-raw` to open the file as one string with line endings intact.

```
"hi`r`nthere`r`nhow`nare`n" | set-content file -NoNewline
get-content -raw file | select-string '\r\n' -AllMatches | % matches | measure


Count    : 2
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

Comment: Many thanks for your kind and useful advice !! I'll post another question for more complicated situation. If you have a chance,  would be appreciated further advice.