# PowerShell : How to count the records, with mixture of CRLF and LF in the same line

Tags: powershell

Let me ask another question from [PowerShell : How to count CRLF, but exclude LF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66689802/powershell-how-to-count-crlf-but-exclude-lf)

I need to handle the records with mixture of CRLF/LF comments column in the line.
The 4th column is for comments which contains both of CRLF and LF like below example.
But I'd like to count only CRLF at the end of the record, after 8 columns.

```
-- record1
"000001","00015066","1","
comment1 <crlf>
comment2 <crlf>
","","2020-03-04 09:40:41","2021-03-17 11:50:14","2021-03-18 00:10:05"**<crlf>**

-- record2
"000002","00015066","1","
comment1 <lf>
comment2 <lf>
","","2020-03-04 09:40:41","2021-03-17 11:50:14","","","","","","2021-03-18 00:10:05"**<crlf>**
```

Could you kindly let me know, how to count only CRLF at the end of records, after 8 columns.
Thank you in advance again.

-- additional information

Thanks to @Theo, csv-import is working fine for this case as long as the file has header.

```
Param(
    [string]$strFileName
)

Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
Write-Host "GET_FILE_ROWS_CNT.ps1"
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

$target = Import-Csv $strFileName -Encoding UTF8
$lines = $target.count
echo $lines
```

Comment: Please define what a "line" is (if not the content _between_ two LF's)

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen  Thanks for your prompt comment. The line means one record. We can import those records to our database,  but can't count correctly the records, since it contains CRLF/LF in the same record.

Comment: what delimits records in your data? you need to find a way to describe that ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for your comment. Line delimiter should be LF.

Comment: Confusing... Are we talking about a CSV file where some (comment) fields can have newlines in them? Then why the weird format in your exampe ?

Comment: @Theo I understand it's strange and it makes me irritated:) Comment column should be free text box at their website. User can enter the CRLF or LF depends on their PC  environment I guess.

Comment: Can you show the code you're currently using? You can process csv files with multi-line string values with something like ```$data = Import-Csv "c:\temp\test.csv" -Header @("a", "b", "c", "comment", "e", "date1", "date2", "date3", "f", "g", "h", "i", "date4")``` so if that doesn't work you might need to provide a bit more context to show what's going wrong for you.

Comment: @mclayton  Appreciated for your example. Just added my current script, useless for the new record format though.

Comment: You speak of `Columns`, so that makes me think the input is a CSV, but you keep us in the dark about the **true** format of the input.. If indeed it **is** csv, then why not simply read it using `Import-CSV` and count the number of records?

Comment: PLEASE explain what the input is.. If it's a text file with the exact format as you show us, then.. Are lines like `-- record1` actually part of the text? Is there always an extra empty line between the records? Without knowing what to deal with, this is impossible to answer

Comment: @Theo Thanks for your comment again. You're right. Just simply I should use 'Import-CSV'... how stupid I am. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @Sachiko - thanks for the feedback ... and i see that Theo pointed out how to use `Import-Csv`. glad to know that you got it working as needed! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Many thanks for your consideration, Lee. Yes, thanks to the experts like you, I solved the issue again .. Stack Overflow always helps me. Have a wonderful day :)

Comment: @Sachiko - [*grin*]